# Liferay: how to delete uploaded files in liferay document library folder programmatically?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I need your help. Does anyone know how to clear uploaded files from data/document_library folder. For example I develop foto upload portlet. And when user upload new foto, the previous should be deleted. 
Here is example of abs example image url. 
 `http://localhost:8080/image/journal/article?img_id=30634`
How I can programatically remove files mapped with such urls?

**UPDATE**

After analyzing liferay database tables (Image and etc.) I have come to desicion:

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(portraitUrl)) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)$");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(portraitUrl);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    ImageLocalServiceUtil.deleteImage(Long.valueOf(matcher.group(0)));
                }
            }
```

Regex search for image id in portrait Url `http://localhost:8080/image/journal/article?img_id=30634`

Comment: Sounds like you a) already solved your problem (?) and b) you are using (at max) Liferay 6.0, as your solution contains ImageLocalServiceUtil, which does not exist anymore since 6.1 - can you confirm both?

Comment: Yes, I solved my problem, but I use liferay 6.2 CE @OlafKock